# javascript : my javascript code not working ??

Tags: javascript, html

it seems that every thing is fine but when i click on the button my dropdown menu doesn't appear , and i think the reason is that the javascript not working !! the styling file in my css folder and it's working fine
here is my code ..

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skin.css"/>
        <title>Change Directory Content</title>
        <script>
            /* When the user clicks on the button,
             toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id ="page">
                <div id="content">                    
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--End Div -->
                        <div class="dropdownL">
                            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br class="clearfix"/>
        </div>

        <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

any help ?

Comment: My best guess, the function gets executed before the page is loaded.

Comment: i have tried to put the script after the html code and in another folder too but it not working

Comment: A general advice: use ID for *unique identificators*, if you need to group nodes in DOM use class or some other attribute, spare yourself the headaches of chasing down your own source of bugs. I'm talking about `id="MyDropdown"`. If you want to duplicate ID then make sure to use the `getElementById/querySelector` on the local root node so that it is really unique in that small place.

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/bwy09fns/ - except for the duplicate id issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do with jquery
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/3brakwtd/1/)

```
<script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button,
         toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myFunction(id) {
            $(id).siblings(".dropdown-content").toggle('slow');
        }
</script>
```

Replace button by 
Dropdown

Comment: thanks that's work for me :)) 
but can you tell me how can i make the list is vertical not horizontal !

Comment: @MohamedNagy Hi I just updated jsfiddle link you can check.

Comment: thank you very much , but there is another issue i have coded javascript function to hide the drop down menu when click on another place in the page but it's not working , can  you show me how can i do it with jquery ?